# How a pass datatable to webservice from fiddler?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, fiddler

I have make two functions in my web service , one for getting all record and second one for updating record . For achieving this , i am used data set(datatable) in web service.

```
[WebMethod( Description = "Returns Northwind Customers", EnableSession = false )]
  public DataSet GetCustomers()
  {
    SqlDataAdapter custDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers", nwindConn);

DataSet custDS = new DataSet();
custDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
custDA.Fill(custDS, "Customers");

return custDS;
  }

 [WebMethod( Description = "Updates Northwind Customers", EnableSession = false )]
  public DataSet UpdateCustomers(DataSet custDS)
  {
SqlDataAdapter custDA = new SqlDataAdapter();

custDA.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) " +
                                      "Values(@CustomerID, @CompanyName)", nwindConn);
custDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
custDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NChar, 15, "CompanyName");

custDA.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers Set CustomerID = @CustomerID, " +
                                      "CompanyName = @CompanyName WHERE CustomerID = @OldCustomerID", nwindConn);
custDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
custDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NChar, 15, "CompanyName");
SqlParameter myParm = custDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@OldCustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
myParm.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

custDA.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID", nwindConn);
myParm = custDA.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
myParm.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

custDA.Update(custDS, "Customers");

return custDS;
  }
```

I want to call this web services from any other client (not net framework ) such as like fiddler or android or php .

Can you plz tell how i call this web services from fiddler for test it . Whether it is working fine or not ?

Suggest me any usuable link or sample code .

Answer (score 0):

Just attach fiddle to your browser's process id and make sure "Capture Traffic" is checked under the "File" menu.

BTW. If you consider to use AJAX for retrieving and updating the GridView then either:

1. Instead of using ASMX just put your grid view to UpdatePanel
2. Instead of using the DataSet as a parameter use `List<MyClass>`, where MyClass defines the data structure of your table and set response format to JSON `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`. You'll then need to build your html table in JavaScript though.

You should use pure JSON as the exchange "mechanism" between client and server.